# Objective-C system("echo ... > ...") not writing to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash, echo, jailbreak

I am trying to execute the following:

```
system("if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; else echo '1' >> /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; fi");
```

However, upon `SSH`-ing into my iPhone, there is no `/var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt` file.

The weird thing about this is that I have another `system()`, which also uses `echo` to insert information into a file:

```
system("(for i in $(echo \"10.0.0.\"{1..255}); do (</dev/tcp/${i}/8008) &> /dev/null && if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo \"${i}\" >> /var/mobile/CCC/HOSTS.txt; fi & done)");
```

Which works fine!!

I have tried placing the

```
system("if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; else echo '1' >> /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; fi");
```

line both before and after the

```
system("(for i in $(echo \"10.0.0.\"{1..255}); do (</dev/tcp/${i}/8008) &> /dev/null && if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo \"${i}\" >> /var/mobile/CCC/HOSTS.txt; fi & done)");
```

line, but there is a `/var/mobile/CCC/HOSTS.txt` file, but no `/var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt` file.

Why is this?

EDIT:

These codes are in my

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
```

method, so upon opening my app, they are automatically executed.

EDIT 2:

After `SSH`-ing into my iPhone, running this command:

```
echo commandSuccessfull && if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; else echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; fi
```

Does work, and produces a `/var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt` file, with the contents in hex: `300a` (`0\n`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace

```
if [[ ${?} == 0]]; then echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; else echo '1' >> /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt"
```

with

```
if [[ ${?} == 0 ]]; then echo '0' > /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt; else echo '1' >> /var/mobile/CCC/STATUS.txt"; fi
```

I have added a necessary space before `]]` and added a missing `; fi`.

Comment: Sorry, me being lazy I forgot to add them in the post. They are in the actual script though :) Good observation though, I'll upvote for that ;)